# SQL Server Native Client Datetime field overflow during migration

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2012, database-migration

I try to migrate from oracle db to sqlserver, after a lot of tries and search, I use [SQLines Data](http://www.sqlines.com/sqldata) to help me creating the script and migrate the data. I face set of problems the most important one right now is:

some data migrated partially and after I analyze the logs, I decide to delete all constrains in the source, but I face another problem :

> ORA-01403: no data found [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client
>   11.0]Datetime field overflow

The log result:

[image]

Comment: I know nothing about that tool or oracle but I certainly would suspect that some value in your source database lies outside the domain of the datatype you are using in sql server. So my first action would be to find the minimum value and the maximum value for that column in your source table. Then look at the domain for your target table and see if those 2 values are compatible. If not, you will need to determine how to handle this column in your migration.

Comment: And perhaps contact support for sqllines - just like it says in your report. And obviously you are using sql server 2012, not 2017. Don't spam the tags just because you MIGHT eventually use a different version.

Comment: Have you tried the Microsoft SQL Server Migration Assistant for Oracle? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54258

Comment: What are the table definitions on both side?